# close MainWindow in pyqt by using menu button

Tags: python, pyqt

I have something like this in python

```
self.dlg = Mainwindow()

self.dlg.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.close)

def close(self):
    QCoreApplication.quit()
```

But the result is that it close a whole software.. I just want to close the mainwindow by using actionExit button.. How can i do that?

Comment: `self.dlg.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.dlg.close)`?

Comment: @DanielSanchez thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `close` over the `MainWindow` instance;

```
self.dlg.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.dlg.close)
```